# Nonparametric Correlation with Dichotomous Variable

Tags: correlation, nonparametric, spearman-rho, kendall-tau

I have a continuous variable (total cholesterol mg/dl) and a dichotomous variable (gender). I want to see whether a relationship exists between the total cholesterol level and gender.

The data is non-normal and the assumptions for point-biserial correlation are violated. Is it appropriate to use a Spearman's Rho or a Kendall's Tau when one variable is dichotomous?